# Remove (network) path from string in VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript

At the moment I am writing a script that has to do with creating a list of files.
I want to remove the root-path from my output. This works for a local path (C:\ProgramData) but it will not work for a network path (\192.168.0.1).

Example of my code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\ProgramData"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Wscript.Echo Replace(objFolder.Path,objStartFolder,"")
```

In my Output I only want <strike>C:\ProgramData</strike>\xyz and <strike>\192.168.0.1</strike>\xyz.

Since I didn't use VBScript before I hope you can help me here.

Comment: How about the parent folder? I cannot test at the moment, but `objFolder.ParentFolder` should return the part you wish to remove, that is, everything up to the last \.

Comment: ParentFolder did the trick. Since I had to extend my script to all subfolders I needed to save the ParentFolder to a variable but it did the trick. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 objFolder.ParentFolder
```

Should return the part you wish to remove, that is, everything up to the last \.

(community wiki, an answer for the sake of it)